Descargar pdf de chrome con Script
Estoy haciendo un script en python para automatizar la descarga de unos archivos PDF, ya logré automatizar todo hasta el punto en el que Chrome abre los PDF, el problema está en que no encuentro como hacer que el script simule el clic en la flechita de descargar que aparece cuando abres un PDF en Chrome. ¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

Saludos. Coloca al menos la estructura basica de tú código (html y javascript) para que te den sugerencias de que cambios hacer; así como acorde a lo que usas orientarte como hacerlo (el lado de Python "podemos" asumir su respuesta es correcta y quizá irrelevante incluir).

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
